# Attempt at code injection

Tags: c, pointers, code-injection, buffer-overflow

I am trying to inject the file contents shown below into the code by way of buffer overflow. Here is my progress so far, I would love to have some help finishing this assignment.

I am getting to the point where i am segfaulting at the strcpy(buffer, input). Anyone know of ways I can get around this? I ask since i can't think of any other ways than using gets() for injecting code.

Also I am running into issues on how I would change the buffer address of the dataFile as said in the assignment

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>



void main(void){

        char *input = NULL;
        size_t length = 0;
        int size = 0;
        FILE *stream;
        char *dataFile = "hw11.data";

        stream = fopen(dataFile, "r");
        printf("before scan\n");

        char buffer[256];



        getline(&input, &length, stream); 

        printf("address: %p\n", buffer);

        printf("input: \n%s\n", input);


        strcpy(buffer, input);


        printf("output: \n%p\n", buffer);


}
```

Hw11.data file below

> python -c 'print
>   "\xeb\x3f\x5f\x80\x77\x0b\x41\x48\x31\xc0\x04\x02\x48\x31\xf6\x0f\x05\x66\x81\xec\xff\x0f\x48\x8d\x34\x24\x48\x89\xc7\x48\x31\xd2\x66\xba\xff\x0f\x48\x31\xc0\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xff\x40\x80\xc7\x01\x48\x89\xc2\x48\x31\xc0\x04\x01\x0f\x05\x48\x31\xc0\x04\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xbc\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x65\x74\x63\x2f\x70\x61\x73\x73\x77\x64\x41"
>   + "A" * 182 + "\x7f\xff\xff\xff\xe0\x00"[::-1]'

This is the assignment that was given

> For this assignment you will write a program that loads the injected
>   code we used in class. However, your program must prevent any buffer
>   overlow. Rules:
>
> 1. The data file will be called hw11.data
> 2. Your buffer must be a static array of length 256
> 3. Your code MUST display the buffer address, the input    data, and the final buffer contents.
> 4. You must change the address in the data file to match     the address of the buffer.
> 5. Your output must be formatted as shown below (your    contents may be slightly different due to text mode     character limitations and
>      address changes):
>
> Buffer Address: 0x7fffffffe000
>
> File Contents: <'python -c 'print "\xeb\x3f\x5f\x80\x77\x0b\x41\ x48\
>   x31\xc0\x04\x02\x48\x31\xf6\x0f\x05\x66\x81\xec\xff\x0f\x48\ x8d\x34\
>   x24\x48\x89\xc7\x48\x31\xd2\x66\xba\xff\x0f\x48\x31\xc0\ x0f\x05\x48\
>   x31\xff\x40\x80\xc7\x01\x48\x89\xc2\x48\x31\xc0\x04\ x01\x0f\x05\x48\
>   x31\xc0\x04\x3c\x0f\x05\xe8\xbc\xff\xff\xff\x2f\ x65\x74\x63\x2f\x70\
>   x61\x73\x73\x77\x64\x41" + "A" * 182 + "\x7f\
>   xff\xff\xff\xe0\x00"[::-1]'
>   >
>
> Buffer Contents: <'python -c 'print "\xeb\x3f\x5f\x80\x77\x0b\x41\ x48\
>   x31\xc0\x04\x02\x48\x31\xf6\x0f\x05\x66\x81\xec\xff\x0f\x48\
>   x8d\x34\x24\ x48\x89\xc7\x48\x31\xd2\x66\xba\xff\x0f\x48\x31\xc0\
>   x0f\x05\x48\x31\xff\ x40\x80\xc7\x01\x48\x89\xc2\x48\x31\xc0\x04\
>   x01\x0f\x05\x48\xpa???>

Comment: The rule said **your program must prevent any buffer overlow** but you're trying to exploit it by buffer overflow. Is it just a file stream practice in C or  I misunderstand it?

Comment: No this is not practice for file stream. Now that I understand the problem I think it was actually for doing something with how I grab the input to prevent it from actually causing a buffer and this adding whatever you can to the buffer without causing the buffer error